# Using linq, can I search a list, access a property, and return a specific instance?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Building.  Each Building has a List of Person.  I am looking for John in the buildings.

Assuming a conventional search might look like this:

```
List<Building> Buildings = CreateBuildings();
foreach(Building building in Buildings)
{
    foreach(Person person in building.PersonList)
    {
         if (person.Name == "John")
         {
             return person;
         }
    }
}
```

Also just because we can, does it mean we should?  So is this an antipattern / misuse of LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like:

```
var query = from building in Buildings
            from person in building.PersonList
            where person.Name == "John"
            select person;
```

That query will find *all* the people with a name of "John". If you want the first such person, or null if no such person can be found, you can use:

```
var john = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that using extension methods you can make this query *slightly* more efficient:

```
var query = Buildings.SelectMany(x => x.PersonList)
                     .Where(x => x.Name == "John");
```

Or for the "first or default" version you can do even better in one step (again, very slightly):

```
var john = Buildings.SelectMany(x => x.PersonList)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "John");
```

These options will avoid using the autogenerated anonymous type that the query expression would use to pair (person, building) together.

And yes, this is a *perfectly* valid use for LINQ - it's exactly the kind of thing it's designed for.

Comment: Why is the 2nd query slighlty faster than the 1st? Is the first query translated into `Select().SelectMany()`, then one useless `Select` ? (I'm not so expert in query syntax...)

Comment: @digEmAll: No, the first version is translated into a SelectMany which converts each pair of results into an instance of an anonymous type. In our case, we don't care about `building`, so there's no point in doing that projection and creating objects we don't need. There's then the saving of another projection from the anonymous type back to the person at the end of the query expression.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, that's one of LINQ's specialties, searching.

```
var buildings = CreateBuildings();
var person = (from building in buildings
              from person in building.PersonList
              where person.Name == "John"
              select person)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or another way to write it:

```
var person = buildings.SelectMany(building => building.PersonList)
                      .FirstOrDefault(person => person.Name == "John");
```

Comment: I certainly can't see why you would :(